# Arch: unable to write to pipe (Broken pipe) when installing selinux-refpoicy-arch

Tags: linux, security, arch-linux, selinux

I'm setting up selinux on my arch system, every library successfully built and the modules were installed, but attempting to apply the reference policies supplied by `selinux-refpolicy-arch` fails after `(2/2) SELinux: relabel installed files` with the error `error: unable to write to pipe (Broken pipe)`

My kernel is `5.15.81-1-lts`

`selinux-refpolicy-arch` is from the aur

Following guide here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SELinux#Installation

No errors encountered following the guide until here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SELinux#Installing_a_policy

If any additional information is appropriate I will add it.

I have looked on google for solutions and only found these three links: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/selinux-hook-error-unable-to-write-to-pipe-broken-pipe/87203/2 https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=237755 and https://www.linux.org/threads/any-idea-how-to-fix-error-unable-to-write-to-pipe-broken-pipe.37247/

None of the above were helpful on account of not containing solutions.

I found more general articles on broken pipe errors, but none were relevant to the problem at hand (fixing pipe errors in apt, dpkg, dnf, pipe from one command to another, etc)

A likely related issue was reported in `selinux-refpolicy-src` here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/selinux-refpolicy-src

No solution is provided in the above to my knowledge.

Checked here: https://github.com/SELinuxProject/refpolicy/issues?q=is%3Aissue+pipe and did not find reference to any related issues.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I ran the following setfiles commands from the selinux-refpolicy-arch repository manually, if this in fact works after reboot I will post here.
NOTE: my install is on nvme1n1p5


`setfiles -E /etc/selinux/refpolicy-arch/contexts/files/file_contexts /dev/nvme1n1p5`

`setfiles -E -v -n /etc/selinux/refpolicy-arch/contexts/files/file_contexts /dev/nvme1n1p5`

`setfiles -E -v /etc/selinux/refpolicy-arch/contexts/files/file_contexts /dev/nvme1n1p5`

Answer (score 1):

The fix in my comment did indeed work, unfortunately I have no clue what the exact cause was.

The fix was, after allowing the command to fail at the last step all the necessary files to complete the install are already on the system, they don't get cleaned up. For each device run the following commands (I ran as root):

```
setfiles -E /etc/selinux/refpolicy-arch/contexts/files/file_contexts/dev/DEVICE 
setfiles -E -v -n /etc/selinux/refpolicy-arch/contexts/files/file_contexts /dev/DEVICE 
setfiles -E -v /etc/selinux/refpolicy-arch/contexts/files/file_contexts /dev/DEVICE
```

I found this out by looking at the tasks done by the install script and makefile in this repo: https://github.com/archlinuxhardened/selinux-policy-arch

The makefile rules I looked at were relabel, checklabels, and restorelabels.

As to why the make file couldn't do this but I could, I have no idea.

Comment: Any information on what caused the issue and why this fix worked would be appreciated! Fixing is good but understanding is better.